# CodeIgniter - Repopulating an invalid form w/ redirect

Tags: php, forms, http, validation, codeigniter

I'm using the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to avoid problems with refreshing the page after a POST submit. The redirect clears any sent POST data, meaning that I cannot populate the fields again with `set_value()` and related functions.

To make this clearer, here is how it works.

1. Client submits a POST with invalid data.
2. A 303 redirect header is sent back.
3. Client does a GET on the header location but POST data is gone, meaning the form cannot be repopulated.

Help pleeeease? :)

Answer (score 6):

Set the the post data as flashdata (part of the session class):

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('post', $this->input->post());
```

Then get it:

```
$this->session->flashdata('post');
```

You can make the data persist longer as well:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('post');
```

For More : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store the POST data in session before redirect e.g. if your form is 'register', then you can do:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['register_form_data'] = array();

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $_SESSION['register_form_data'][$key] = $value;
}
```

Now the form data will be available on form page. You can also create a `set_value_from_session()` helper function to repopulate the fields.

Comment: This is not standard usage for CodeIgniter.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know about flashdata. I was talking more in general.

Comment: No worries - just letting ya know = )

Answer (score 0):

you could extend CI_Form_validation and add (or add this to CI_Form_validation construct)

`$CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->library('session');
            if (count($_POST) > 0 OR count($_FILES) > 0)
            {
                $CI->session->set_flashdata('prg', array(
                    'date'  => time()+ini_get('max_execution_time'),
                    'post'  => $_POST,
                    'files' => $_FILES
                ));
                redirect(current_url(), 'location', 302);
            }
            else{
                $prg = $CI->session->flashdata('prg');
                if($prg==TRUE){
                    if($prg['date']>time()){
                        $_POST  = $prg['post'];
                        $_FILES = $prg['files'];
                    }
                }
            }`

to the construct.
This will fix your issue
But if you have any redirect() functions after form submissions in system, those redirects will be overridden from above redirect. so please pay attention to that.
(work-around - you could call this in every function where redirect() is not present )